# What is the "ls" directory in my home directory?

Tags: terminal, finder, unix, filesystem

I was just exploring the directory structure on my Mac and there's a directory in my root/home directory, named `ls`.

```
[~]$ ls -l .
.
.
drwxr-xr-x   6 XXXX  staff       192 Dec  8  2018 ls
```

```
[~/ls]$ pwd
/Users/XXXX/ls
```

Could someone help me understand what this directory holds and why is in the  root?

The `ls` command should reference the `/bin/ls` command, I'm guessing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you open the directory and look inside?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That `ls/` directory is not standard on Mac, so its something you or another user on the Mac have created (either directly, or indirectly by being created by some third party program).

It hasn't got anything to do with the `ls` command. However, it could reasonably have been made by someone in the middle of a `mkdir` command thinking that they should just list the directory first - and then erraneously running `mkdir ls`.

By the way - the directory `/Users/xxxx` is not called the `root` directory, but rather the user's home directory.

Comment: Sounds about right. I currently have `-p` and `--help` directories in my home directory, presumably from commands that were incorrectly piped into `mkdir` or similar.